# SAS is separating PROC MEANS in by variable

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that I need to group by two variables and show the means of those  records in a BY clause. The problem is the output separates the table into a MEANS for each grouping and places a "Product=xxxx" above it. I want the table to be a combined list

here is the code.

```
PROC MEANS DATA=saledata mean stddev min q1 median q3 max maxdec=2 nway order=data c;
    OUTPUT out=saledata3 mean= ;
    OPTIONS BYLINE ;
    CLASS Product SaleType;
    FORMAT Product SaleType $salefmt. Pop Quantity Amount;
    TITLE "Assignment 2.e";
```

And I get something like this
[image]
.
I want to remove the header and the Product= portion. Also, how do I add gridliens?

Comment: Try using a BY statement instead of a CLASS. You may need to use PROC TABULATE instead though.

Comment: I reordered the input sets sorting priority and now it appears to have worked.  Now still trying to get the grid lines to show between the variables

Comment: Where exactly do you want gridlines? It's best to show a sample like you did for the question above.